# Triggering Script in google Sheets after Forms Submit

Tags: triggers, google-sheets, libraries, google-forms, onsubmit

I have a working script in one of my google sheets projects, but now I want it to be triggered when I hit the submit button on a Google Form I have. Basically, the data from my Google Form gets exported to my Sheets form, but then I have a script to analyze the data entered. For some reason, it seems like it's doing nothing when the onSubmitForm() function is triggered. It's clear there's a problem because my logger test line displays for the onSubmitForm function but not for the EvaluateResults function.

The code in my Google Form is simple:

```
function onSubmitForm(){
   Logger.log("onSubmitForm Running");
   a.EvaluateResults();
}
```

The code in the Google Sheets is simple as well:

```
function EvaluateResults(){
  Logger.log("evaluation running");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet_results = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  var sheet_userForm = ss.getSheetByName("Form Responses 1");

  sheet_results.getRange("C24").setValue((sheet_userForm.getRange("A2").getValue());
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write the entire function in Google form script itself. You can collect the response from Google form as soon as the submit is hit.

```
function onSubmitForm(e){
  Logger.log("onSubmitForm Running");
  var itemResponses = e.response.getItemResponses();
  var emailAddress = itemResponses[1].getResponse(); // Response of second question
  Logger.log(emailAddress)
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SS ID"); // Replace with your Spreadsheet Id
  var sheet_results = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2");
  sheet_results.getRange("C24").setValue(emailAddress);
}
```